# Xamarin Forms | Entry | Add text and delete

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.entry

I have an entry in Xamarin Forms that accepts numbers and I want to add a unit at the end.
They input:

> 163.23

And and it automatically changes it to:

> 163.23 mm

And when they focus it again or click on it, it gets deleted and they input into it again.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a label with the text 'mm' behind the entry.

Another option is to use StringFormat or a custom formatter.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/ has a sample StringFormat and DoubleToIntConverter.